# preg_replace bracket '('

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to turn `(05 May, 2012` in to `05 May, 2012` with preg_replace (basically removing brackets), but since I am useless with regex I have no idea how to do this

**code attempts**

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/', '(05 May, 2012', $matches);
if($matches){
   $match= $matches[0];
}else{
   $match= '';
}


$match = preg_replace('/[0-9]+(?:[0-9]*,)?/','$1','(05 May, 2012');
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: why don't you just use `str_replace()`??

Comment: like I said im useless at regex, there was no need to shame me @bažmegakapa

Comment: @mk_89 Of course I had no intention of shaming you. If you are not good enough in something, learning is better in the long run than asking someone to do it instead of you. There are thousands of regex tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Hi @mk_89. I've reverted your edit to remove this post entirely, since an empty question isn't very useful for future readers. Don't worry about downvotes or question closes - they happen to pretty much everyone in their time here. Just learn from the situation, and continue to ask/answer questions `:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're "useless" with regex use a simpler function then

```
$date = trim($date,"()");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = preg_replace('/\(([0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+\, [0-9]{4})/','$1',$date);
```